# How to save a plotly graph keeping its interactivity

Tags: python, plotly

I finished my plotly scatterplot and I'm trying to save it to be able to present it in a presentation, for instance power point (tho it could be pdf format as well). If I save it, it is saved in png format, as a picture, and it loses the interactivity, which is the fundamental part of the graph. How can I save it with the interactive condition?
[image: 1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course is not possible to export an interactive PNG, but you can export the graph in html using `fig.write_html`.

As an example:

```py
import plotly.express as px
fig =px.scatter(x=range(20), y=range(20))
fig.write_html("file.html")
```

This will create a file in the same folder of your code called "file.html".

If you open this file with a browser, it will result in:
[image: Generated HTML]

You can open this file as any other HTML file, and you can interact with the graph (than you can integrate it wherever you want).

Here you can find the documentation: https://plotly.com/python/interactive-html-export/ where you can find the alternative with Dash too.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I've tried that but it gives me the error "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'path/to/file.html'". It's my understanding that I need to use fig.write_html("path/to/file.html") but I don't know what to put instead of "path/to/file.html".

Comment: you need to write the path to to file (that will be created if it doesn't exist). As an example fig.write_html("file.html") to save directly in the same folder of the .py file or of the Jupyter Notebook

Comment: That worked but I don't understand. Where is that saved? How can I see the graph and access it?

Comment: It is just an HTML file, you can open it with a browser (or embed it in your webpage).

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't understand how to open it. What do I search for on a browser? I can't click on anything, I don't understand where it's created.

Comment: In the same folder of your .py file (or .ipynb), after that you run your code, you will have a file which ends in .html.

You can open this file using Firefox, Chrome or any other browser with a double click on the file, a right click followed by "open with", or pasting the path to the file in your browser

Comment: You do not have to open your .py file. You run the code in the pyfile and this will produce a file (I edited the answer with an example) that will be saved in the file of your .py (in your case, on Colab).
If you don't have an html file, please check your code and be sure you implemented it as suggested.

Comment: I just found the html file!! Thank you so much for your time, I'm sorry it took me so long to get it. I'm truly thankful.